# Insertion Sort (descending order) -- what am I missing here?

Tags: c, sorting, insertion-sort

So, I'm struggling pretty hard on this insertion sort algorithm, I can't understand why I'm getting this output. I've gone through it on paper and it works there as I step through it...what is going on?

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

   int arrayIn[5];


   /* Insertion func */

   printf("==============================\n");

   for(int k=0; k<5; k++){
      arrayIn[k] = k + 1;
   }

   for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++){
      printf("array[%d]: %d \n", y, arrayIn[y]);
   }

   //insertion

   for (int j = 1; j < 5 - 1; j++) {
      int i = j - 1;
      int temp = arrayIn[j];

      while (i >= 0 && arrayIn[i] < arrayIn[j] /* Aj < Ai */) {
         arrayIn[i+1] = arrayIn[i];
         i--;
      }
      arrayIn[i+1] = temp;

   }

   for(int p = 0; p < 5; p++){
      printf("array[%d]: %d \n", p, arrayIn[p]);
   }   



   return(0);
}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

Before insertion sort:

```
array[0]: 1 
array[1]: 2 
array[2]: 3 
array[3]: 4 
array[4]: 5
```

After insertion sort:

```
array[0]: 2 
array[1]: 3 
array[2]: 4 
array[3]: 1 
array[4]: 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While condition is wrong:

```
while (i >= 0 && arrayIn[i] < arrayIn[j])
```

Should be:

```
while (i >= 0 && arrayIn[i] < temp)
```

Because `arrayIn[j]`  is nothing but `arrayIn[i + 1]` in first iteration in while loop that can be over-written in `arrayIn[i+1] = arrayIn[i];` in while.

In insertion sort you insert a value in sorted array, In outer loop you reads `arrayIn[j]` in `temp`. Now you are to insert `temp` at sorted position, and for every `arrayIn[i]` that is smaller than `temp` a shift needed `arrayIn[i+1] = arrayIn[i];` At first time you may write to `arrayIn[j] = arrayIn[i];`  if `arrayIn[j] > arrayIn[i];` because `j = i + 1`.

Edit, from @[M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979617/m-oehm): 
Yours outer for loop run just for i = 1 to 3 and doesn't insert `arrayIn[4]` to sorted position, change `j < 5 - 1;` to `j < 5`.

Comment: yeah, I just realized that myself. However, my output still is not quite right...

Comment: You must also adjust the outer loop to run from `[1:5)`: `for (int j = 1; j < 5 - 1; j++)`.